# How to reorder a character vector of coefficient names by order of appearance in a list of models

Tags: r, sorting, stargazer, tidyverse

The [stargazer package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stargazer) in R is fantastic for displaying multiple regression models as side-by-side columns—the standard style for many social science disciplines. However, the package doesn't play well with knitr+pandoc, since it generates output either as HTML or TeX, but not Markdown.

As a solution, I'm creating a function that can generate tables similar to those created with stargazer, but that saves the output as a simple data frame, which I can then render with pacakges like `kable` and `pander` in knitted documents. Doing this is trivial with functions like `broom::tidy`.

I'm stuck, however, on how to order the coefficients displayed in the model. Take these three models, for example. When displayed with stargazer, the final coefficient order is `c("wt", "qsec", "hp", "cyl", "gear", "carb", "drat")`. The order of all the coefficients is based primarily on the coefficients in the first model (`wt`, `qsec`, `cyl`, `gear`, `carb`). When the second model is appended as a new column, the `hp` row is inserted after `qsec` and before `cyl`.

```r
lm0 <- lm(hp ~ wt + qsec + cyl + gear + carb, mtcars)
lm1 <- lm(qsec ~ hp + cyl + gear + carb, mtcars)
lm2 <- lm(qsec ~ wt + hp + gear + drat, mtcars)

stargazer(lm0, lm1, lm2, type="text")
```

```
====================================================
              (1)           (2)             (3)          
----------------------------------------------------
wt           16.879                       0.827**        
            (12.113)                      (0.383)        
qsec         -8.124                                      
            (6.109)                                      
hp                         -0.005        -0.026***       
                          (0.007)         (0.004)        
cyl         18.210**     -0.811***                       
            (8.785)       (0.280)                        
gear         13.342      -1.597***         -0.232        
            (15.115)      (0.441)         (0.439)        
carb         9.277         0.098                         
            (6.345)       (0.222)                        
drat                                       0.099         
                                          (0.636)        
Constant     49.424      29.181***       19.530***       
           (171.876)      (2.398)         (2.766)        
====================================================
Note:                    *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

In the end, I hope to generate a character vector of the coefficient names that I can then use with `dplyr::arrange()` to correctly sort a data frame of multiple model coefficients.

The sorting seems to follow this pseudo algorithm:

1. Save the first list (`list_1`) of coefficient names
2. Go through the second list of names. If `element_1` of `list_2` doesn't match `element_1` of `list_1`, check the next element of `list_1` until there's a match, then insert before the match
3. Put `element_2` of `list_2` after `element_1` if it doesn't match anything else in `list_1`
4. Repeat with `list_3`, and so on

Writing simple R code to generate this order, however, has proven more difficult than I thought. Simply concatenating all the coefficient names in a vector and then keeping only unique values doesn't product the correct order, since new variables (like `hp`) are just added to the end of existing variable names instead of getting inserted in the middle:

```r
library(tidyverse)
names1 <- names(lm0$coefficients) %>% discard(~ .x == "(Intercept)")
names2 <- names(lm1$coefficients) %>% discard(~ .x == "(Intercept)")
names3 <- names(lm2$coefficients) %>% discard(~ .x == "(Intercept)")

# New variables just appended
unique(c(names1, names2, names3))

# [1] "wt"   "qsec" "cyl"  "gear" "carb" "hp"   "drat"
```

Additionally, it seems like the only way to implement something like this is to use a ton of loops, which feels wildly inefficient.

So, in the end, how can I sort or reorder a character vector of coefficient names by order of appearance in a list of models, prioritizing the order of the first model in the list? That is, ultimately this is the character vector I'd like to get: `c("wt", "qsec", "hp", "cyl", "gear", "carb", "drat")`

---

Update: `memisc::mtable(lm0, lm1, lm2)` is a [neat alternative to stargazer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24369399/120898) that actually returns a data frame (and not just text), but it doesn't insert new coefficients in the already existing order and instead appends them to the list (with `hp` and `drat` at the end). It seems to just concatenate all the coefficient names and use their unique values.

```
===================================================
                     lm0        lm1        lm2     
---------------------------------------------------
  (Intercept)       49.424   29.181***  19.530***  
                  (171.876)  (2.398)    (2.766)    
  wt                16.879               0.827*    
                   (12.113)             (0.383)    
  qsec              -8.124                         
                    (6.109)                        
  cyl               18.210*  -0.811**              
                    (8.785)  (0.280)               
  gear              13.342   -1.597**   -0.232     
                   (15.115)  (0.441)    (0.439)    
  carb               9.277    0.098                
                    (6.345)  (0.222)               
  hp                         -0.005     -0.026***  
                             (0.007)    (0.004)    
  drat                                   0.099     
                                        (0.636)    
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the Q of the OP

> So, in the end, how can I sort or reorder a character vector of coefficient names by order of appearance in a list of models, prioritizing the order of the first model in the list?

here is a one-liner which should work for an arbitary number of models:

```
unique(names(unlist(lapply(list(lm0, lm1, lm2), coef))))[-1]
#[1] "wt"   "qsec" "cyl"  "gear" "carb" "hp"   "drat"
```

Note that the code makes the implicit assumption that the first model always has `"(Intercept)"` as first coefficient which is removed from the result vector by negative indexing `[-1]`.

If this can't be guaranteed it might be safer to use

```
setdiff(unique(names(unlist(lapply(list(lm0, lm1, lm2), coef)))), "(Intercept)")
```

to remove `"(Intercept)"` from the result vector if there is any and irrespectively of its position. The remaining coefficient names will maintain their order:

```
#[1] "wt"   "qsec" "cyl"  "gear" "carb" "hp"   "drat"
```

---

**Edit**

It's not quite clear which logic `stargazer` has implemented to order the coefficients. However, according to the help page, `stargazer` *also returns the same output invisibly as a character vector.* In addition, the `table.layout` parameter can be utilized to only return the coefficient section. This can be used to extract the names of the coefficient in the same order as `stargazer`:

```
sgt <- capture.output(stargazer::stargazer(lm0, lm1, lm2, type="text", table.layout = "t"))
setdiff(stringr::str_extract(sgt, "^\\w*"), c("", "Constant"))
#[1] "wt"   "qsec" "hp"   "cyl"  "gear" "carb" "drat"
```

As `stargazer` uses `cat()` to output, `capture.output()` keeps the console output clean (Thanks to @Andrew for suggesting this).

The *regular expression* in `str_extract()` returns the first "word" at the beginning of each string. The result vector is again cleaned up using `setdiff()`.

Comment: Ooh, I like the simplicity of this. The one thing it's missing is the placement of `hp` in between `qsec` and `cyl` like in stargazer—the desired output places `hp` earlier because it's a new variable, but it appears before existing variables like `cyl` and `gear`

Comment: @Andrew Found another solution by extracting the coefficient names directly  from `stargazer`output.

Comment: Awesome. I had tried recreating stargazer's original logic, but its code for it 200ish lines of nested loops and it's almost inscrutable. Relying on stargazer to do the heavy lifting instead is a lot easier, especially with `table.layout="t"` limiting the output.

Comment: Also, wrapping it all in `capture.output()` keeps the console output clean, since stargazer automatically `cat()`s the output: `capture.output({ sgt <- ... }, file="/dev/null")`