# Reporting regression tables using rmarkdown in Word format

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Trying to report regression tables in Word format using rmarkdown seems impossible. After trying hours and several options like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342162/regression-tables-in-markdown-format-for-flexible-use-in-r-markdown-v2) no one worked in my case. I want to report `lm` models using markdown and render to a .doc file.

#### Method 1:

Using `memisc` package to create a `mtable` object and render using `pander`:

```
> lm0 <- lm(hp ~ wt, mtcars)
> lm1 <- lm(qsec ~ hp, mtcars)
> lm2 <- lm(qsec ~ wt, mtcars)
> 
> library(memisc)
> 
> mt <- mtable(lm0, lm1, lm2)
> 
> pander::pander(mt)
Error in x[[i]] : subíndice fuera de  los límites
Además: Warning message:
In pander.default(mt) :
  No pander.method for "memisc_mtable", reverting to default.
```

#### Method 2:

Create a html object and include using `includeHTML`. So far this is the closed method to my desire output. However the table only contains one column like this:

````
```{r}
stargazer::stargazer(lm0, lm1, lm2, type = "html", title = "Results", out = "./pp.html")
shiny::includeHTML("pp.html")
```
````

Code above produces this in a word document:
[image]

#### Method 3:

Using `xtable` also produces the same output above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I usually produce HTML page using any library, then copy past to word.

Comment: @A.Suliman thanks but I don't want copy-past process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `write_html` (from the memisc package):

```
write_html(mt, "mt.html")
```

Now open the mt.html file in Word.  This is what it looks like in Word. (continued after screenshot)

[image: screenshot]

Alternately use this to convert filePathIn (which is the path to the html file created) to filePathOut (which is the path to the docx file to be created from it).  This works on Windows and even in cases where pandoc does not as it uses Word itself to do the translation from html to docx. (If you want a doc file rather than docx then replace "docx" with "doc" in the filePathOut definition and replace 16 with 0 in the SaveAs line.  See [wdSaveFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdsaveformat-enumeration-word).)

```
library(RDCOMClient)

filePathIn <- file.path(getwd(), "mt.html")
filePathOut <- sub("html$", "docx", filePathIn)

w <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
doc <- w[["Documents"]]
od <- doc$Open(filePathIn)
od$SaveAs(filePathOut, 16)
w$Quit()
```

Comment: Definitely exporting as `html` format and then transform in `word` seems to be the easiest and coolest approach! Thanks!!

Comment: Note this also works with `stargazer(type = "html", out = "filepath.html")`, open with Word, Save as docx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplistic way to store regression outputs:

```
sink("myresult.doc", append=T)
```

All outputs will be appending automatically as long as this is specified: `append=T`

HTH